# calculate Business Day and tie it to date in each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, calendar

I need a way to tie the business day of a month to that particular date for a calendar generator.  I am able to correctly generate the calendar, but cannot get the business days to populate.

For instance, if 01/01/1999 is a Saturday, the first business day is 01/04/1999, and the next business day is 01/05/1999.  So my table needs to look like this

```
Date                Business Date        BusinessDay    BusinessDaysRemaining
01/01/1999          01/04/1999               1                 19  
01/02/1999          01/04/1999               1                 19
01/03/1999          01/04/1999               1                 19
01/04/1999          01/04/1999               1                 19
01/05/1999          01/05/1999               2                 18
01/06/1999          01/06/1999               3                 17
Etc...
```

Then this will start over again the next month.  In other months (and weekends) the business date goes back to Friday before the weekend, this is just one example of what I am trying to accomplish.

I dont know where to start on this, so any help would be appreciated.

This is in MS SQL 2008 R2

Comment: MS SQL 2008 V2.  I added that to my question as well.

Comment: I think the vote to close this question is unjustified.  If it does close, I hope others will join me in re-opening it.

Comment: Does your table have a holiday column?  If not, you might need it unless you consider those to be business days.

Comment: Yes, holidays are in the master Calendar table and are already elimindated from the dates in the sub-table I created. So the list of Business Dates in this table already have Weekends and Holidays eliminated.

Comment: If 01/01/1999 is a Saturday, then isn't 01/03/1999, (the Monday following that Saturday) a Business Day? If you are saying you eliminated Holidays already, how come 01/03/1999 in your expected table have 01/04/1999 as the business date for 01/03/1999?

Comment: 1/3/99 would be celebrated as New years Day and our business would be closed, making 1/4/99 the first business day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer, I created a table called Calendar.  The primary key is TheDate datatype date.  Other fields are HolidayName (nullable varchar), BusinessDayOfMonth tinyint default 0, and BusinessDaysRemainingInMonth tinyint default 0.  I then entered records for December 2013, which has two holidays - Christmas and Boxing Day.

Here are my updates.

```
update Calendar
set BusinessDayOfMonth = therank
from Calendar join
(
select TheDate
, rank() over 
(partition by cast(datepart(year, thedate) as varchar) +  cast(datepart(month, thedate) 
as varchar) 
order by thedate) therank

from Calendar
where HolidayName is null
and DATEPART(dw,thedate) between 2 and 6  -- Monday to Friday
) temp on Calendar.TheDate = temp.TheDate


declare @BusinessDays as tinyint
set @BusinessDays =
(select count(1) BusinessDays
from Calendar
where BusinessDayOfMonth > 0
)

update Calendar
set BusinessDaysRemainingInMonth = @BusinessDays - BusinessDayOfMonth
where BusinessDayOfMonth > 0
```

In your case, you are going to need a date range of course.  Plus, you are going to have to update the BusinessDaysRemainingInMonth field for the weekends and holidays.  If you need help with that, I suggest a separate question.

Comment: I had to make some minor modifications but this did work.  thank you Dan!